# Splitting up a wav file in to several clips - java

Tags: java, sockets, audio, network-programming

I'm reading a wav file from disk to send over a socket to a client. 
While I have this working, I currently have to stream the whole file in one go, which while does allow the client to play it back takes a noticeable amount of time to occur(around 5 seconds) and I would like the playback to be instant.

My planned solution for this is to stream the file 5 second clips at a time and play them back sequentially, but  I am struggling to split the file in to 5 second segments that can be sent over the socket to the client and the client can then play back.

**Source code**

**Server - loading and sending the song**

```
            System.out.println("Waiting for a connection");
            Socket client = socket.accept();
            OutputStream stream = client.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("WTMS.wav"));

            int bytesNeeded = bytesNeeded(new File("WTMS.wav"));
            System.out.println("Need " + bytesNeeded + " bytes for 5 seconds");
            byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                stream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
```

**Client code - receiving and playing the song**

This code occurs once the socket has connected to the server and the server has told the client it's about to send the song. inputStream is a data input stream obtained from the connected socket.

```
           System.out.println("Playing");
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
            try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
                clip.open(ais);
                clip.start();
                Thread.sleep(100);
                clip.drain();

            }
```

Of all of the solutions I have tried, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507956/1922571  appeared the most likely to work, but I ran in to the same problem as the person who asked the question, I am unsure how to use the AudioSystem.write method. I would prefer to keep the 5 second clips in memory and not have to write them to disk at any point if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**EDIT Using a SourceDataLine as suggested in the comments works to fix this.**

Comment: have you written anything that plays the file using the SourceDataLine? try that then we will see

Comment: Since .wav files are uncompressed, you might be able to alleviate your problem by wrapping your socket’s OutputStream in a [GZIPOutputStream.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html), and on the client side, wrapping the InputStream in a [GZIPInputStream.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html).

Comment: Thanks gpasch, I hadn't come across SourceDataLine but now I'm using it the playback is instant. 

Thanks again :)